# _ttoi win c++ assertion failure

Tags: c++, c, winapi

i have this code:

```
BOOLEAN   Recurse = FALSE;
DWORD     NumPasses = 1;


int _tmain( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] ) 
{

    BOOL        foundFileArg = FALSE;
    int         i;

   if( argc < 2 ) {

        return Usage( argv[0] );
    }


    for( i = 1; i < argc; i++ ) {

        if( !_tcsicmp( argv[i], TEXT("/s") ) ||
            !_tcsicmp( argv[i], TEXT("-s") )) {

            Recurse = TRUE;

    } else if( !_tcsicmp( argv[i], TEXT("/p") ) ||
                   !_tcsicmp( argv[i], TEXT("-p") )) {

                   // assertion failure 
            NumPasses = argc > i ? _ttoi( argv[i+1] ) : 1;
            if( !NumPasses ) return Usage( argv[0] );
            i++;


        } else {

            if( foundFileArg ) return Usage( argv[0] );
            foundFileArg = TRUE;
        }
    }


    return 0;

}
```

i get assertion failure,
Please suggest where the problem might be and where to look. Is it some problem with _ttoi function i'm using when it fails,
if i have to allocate a buffer,
how can i resolve it

thanks

Comment: You can't do this "argv[i+1]". You are looping through all the command line provided arguments and with that expression you are trying to access one past the last one.

Comment: he has tri operator to handle that. but it should be argc > i+1 instead of argc > i

Answer (score 1):

this line

```
NumPasses = argc > i ? _ttoi( argv[i+1] ) : 1;
```

should be

```
NumPasses = argc > 1+i ? _ttoi( argv[i+1] ) : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nick is right; don't forget that arrays start at zero in C/C++.  If there are 5 elements, it means argv[0] to argv[4] are valid - not argv[5].